# How to validate by clicking a button a new tab will be opened in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am having a button. while clicking on the button a new tab will be opened, i will validate that page and get back to the previous tab. how to validate tabs

Comment: Welcome to [so] where we aim to assist you with your programming difficulties. A good question contains certain information as described in the [ask] section of the [help]. Chief among them is the [mcve]. If you have tried several approaches, it helps to highlight them and the observed results. This prevents unnecessary questions for clarifications and probably increases the number of answers and their suitability for your specific situation.

Comment: @WojtekT: I don't think this is a duplicate of that. The one you link to is asking _how_ to open in a new tab. This question is about verifying that a link actually opened a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using [SeleniumLibrary](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html), one simple solution is to get a list of window handles before and after clicking the link. The number of handles after should be one greater than before clicking the button.

You can use [Get window handles](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Window%20Handles) to get a list of window handles, and you can then use [Select window](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Window) to get back to the original window, or any other open tab or window.

Comment: using with Select Window i solve this issue. "Select Window  tabname"